# Does manipulating n have any impact on the O of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

Does manipulating `n` have any impact on the O of an algorithm?

recursive code for example:

```
Public void Foo(int n)
{
  n -= 1;
  if(n <= 0) return;
  n -= 1;
  if(n <= 0) return;

  Foo(n)
}
```

Does the reassignment of `n` impact `O(N)`? Sounds intuitive to me...

Does this algorithm have `O(N)` by dropping the constant? Technically, since it's decrementing `n` by 2, it would not have the same mathematical effect as this:

```
public void Foo(int n) // O(Log n)
{
  if(n <= 0) return;
  Console.WriteLine(n);
  Foo(n / 2);
}
```

But wouldn't the halving of `n` contribute to `O(N)`, since you are only touching *half* of the amount of `n`? To be clear, I am learning O Notation and it's subtleties. I have been looking for cases such that are like the first example, but I am having a hard time finding such a specific answer.

Comment: That is a good trick to circumvent the `O(n)` notation and pack more operations in :-)

Comment: @Sebastian That was the intention for my own code. I just didn't 100% know how to refer to it, in terms of Big O. Didn't want to go around spouting some imprecise mumbo jumbo lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reassignment of n itself is not really what matters when talking about O notation. As an example consider a simple for-loop:

```
for i in range(n):
   do_something()
```

In this algorithm, we do something n times. This would be equivalent to the following algorithm

```
while n > 0:
   do_something()
   n -= 1
```

And is equivalent to the first recursive function you presented. So what really matters is how many computations is done compared to the input size, which is the original value of n.
For this reason, all these three algorithms would be O(n) algorithms, since all three of them decreases the 'input size' by one each time. Even if they had increased it by 2, it would still be a O(n) algorithm, since constants doesn't matter when using O notation. Thus the following algorithm is also a O(n) algorithm.

```
while n > 0:
    do something()
    n -= 2
```

or

```
while n > 0:
    do_something()
    n -= 100000
```

However, the second recursive function you presented is a O(log n) algorithm (even though it does not have a base case and would techniqually run till the stack overflows), as you've written in the comments. Intuitively, what happens i that when halving the input size every time, this exactly corresponds to taking the logarithm in base two of the original input number. Consider the following:

n = 32. The algorithm halves every time: 32 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1.
In total, we did 5 computations. Equivalently log2(32) = 5.

So to recap, what matters is the original input size and how many computations is done compared to this input size. Whatever constant may affect the computations does not matter.

If I misunderstood your question, or you have follow up questions, feel free to comment this answer.

Comment: This is as I expected, to beat a dead horse: The constants dropped don't affect runtime, but can have significant impact on performance 'in the real world'. Is that right?

Comment: It definitely has an effect on both performance and runtime, it's just not the most important aspect when considering systems with extremely large input sizes. That is not to say you should not consider it.


If you have a database with maybe 100000 records, it definitely matters if your algorithms uses n computations or 2n computations. But what matters much more is if the algorithm is an O(n) algorithm or O(n²), since O(n) would be 100000 computations, and O(n²) would be 10000000000 computations. The importance being bigger the larger n is.

Comment: Great, thank you. That helps a lot. I appreciate the detailed answer! Using Big O notation is just on a way larger scope than I had originally considered (I think.) Cool stuff!

Comment: Fun little side note as how O notation is not the only thing that matters, read about [Galactic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_algorithm). The first that came to my mind is when doing matrix multiplications, the current 'fastest' algorithm is a galactic algorithms, which would not make sense in real life practices.